# efficient way to look for all css uses of a color

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

What is the most efficient way to look for all uses of a css color in the "current page" ?
For me a use of a color appear as color-background, font color, border color.
In table TDs, Divs, Span, paragraph (P), etc....

I think to do a similar "loop" to this one is overkill for a full page, and this one is just searching a specific HTML tag (DIV) and verifying only the "color", not the other properties....

```
$("div").each(function () {
    var color = $(this).css("color");
    if (color == "#F1F2F3") {
        console.log('found it!');
    }
});
```

Isn't there a easiest way to simple say: "replace all HEX color #XXXXXX value for #YYYYYY ?????

In css I might even represent the color in different ways (at least 5 ways):

```
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #000;
    border: 1px solid rgb(0,0,0);
    border-bottom-color: rgb(0%,0%,0%);
    outline-color: black;
```

Update 1

I took Garath sugestion and I worked a little on it (all selector with exclusion, etc), but I am still not so happy about it..... I am still trying to identify all different properties where the color might exist, and I am not even paying attention to the way the browser will return me the color.....

```
$('*:not(head, script,link, meta, title)').filter(function() { 
    var replace = 'rgb(0, 0, 0)';
    var replaceFor = '#FF0000';
    if( $(this).css('color') == replace)  $(this).css('color', replaceFor); 
    if( $(this).css('background-color') == replace)  $(this).css('background-color', replaceFor); 
    if( $(this).css('border-color') == replace)  $(this).css('border-color', replaceFor); 
});
```

It would be so great to have a similar way to this one [Attribute Equals Selector [name="value"]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/), but where I would not need to specify the attribute type...

Comment: Note: _Different browsers may return CSS color values that are logically but not textually equal, e.g., #FFF, #ffffff, and rgb(255,255,255) -- http://api.jquery.com/css/._

Comment: @web-tiki for my purpose I need to have it written in the code and not be dependent on a webbroswer plugin/extension.

Comment: What do you mean by `to look for all uses of a css color` ? Do you just want to print something like `found color xxx` or do you need something else ? Please explain what is the point of doing that.

Comment: Don't forget to iterate through the style sheets, not only the inline styles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of each function you can use filter, but still it have to check all elements - fortunately it the complexity of this check is linear.
The snippet could look like this:

```
$('div').filter(function() {
    var match = '#F1F2F3';
    return ( $(this).css('color') == match );
}).css('color', '#YYYYYY');
```